# VBA Check If Textbox Is Null then send message

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

first end second if statments working (combobox and textbox <10 ) but third is not(null value). Why?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then
MsgBox "bla"
Exit Sub
End If
If CDbl(TextBox1.Text) < 10 Then
    MsgBox "bla!"
Exit Sub
End If
If (TextBox1.Value = Null) Then
    MsgBox "bla!"
End If
Exit Sub
```

Comment: `(TextBox1.Value = "")`

Comment: not work ı already try it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think there is logical error when ı try to reverse if condition between null and smaller its worked. Here  is the correct form;

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then
MsgBox "bla"
Exit Sub
End If
End If
If TextBox1.Text= "" Then
    MsgBox "bla!"
End If
Exit Sub
If CDbl(TextBox1.Text) < 10 Then
    MsgBox "bla!"
Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare with *Null*. Use `IsNull`:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then
       MsgBox "bla"
       Exit Sub
    End If
    If CDbl(TextBox1.Text) < 10 Then
       MsgBox "bla!"
    Exit Sub
    End If
    If IsNull(TextBox1.Value) Then
       MsgBox "bla!"
    End If

Exit Sub
```